# std::vector assigning value SIGNAL 11 and SIGNAL 6

Tags: c++, linux, vector

Here is the part of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
unsigned long k,p,q, all;


cin >> k >> p >> q; 
vector<long> klo(k);
all = 0;
for(unsigned long i = 0;i<k;i++){
    scanf("%d", &klo[i]);
    all += klo[i];
}
vector<unsigned long> stack(all);


stack[1] = 1;
stack.at(2) = 2;

....REST OF THE CODE....

return 0;
}
```

It compiles on Windows and Linux. Works with no problem on windows, but when I try running it on Linux `stack[1] = 1;` shows `Error: signal: 11` and `stack.at(2) = 2;`: `Error: signal:6`
What's the problem?

@EDIT: I found out that `all` variable is empty. Seems that `all += klo[i];` does not return the proper value. But don't know why this code works in Windows

Comment: i was looking at std::stack documentation for like 5 minutes looking for a ctor that takes the stored type, you and your names....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `vector<unsigned long> stack(all);` is reached, it seems that `all` is 0.

Comment: Correct. Read my @EDIT, why doesn't it work in Linux?

Comment: @Disa: if the vector `klo` properly filled when `scanf` is called?

Comment: @Disa: `scanf("%ld", &klo[i]);` should fix the problem, according to `scanf` man page